Element overrining while pushing element
let header = [];

for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
  header.push(`header${index}`);
}

let datacell = [];

for (let index = 0; index < 64; index++) {
  datacell.push(`datacell${index}`);
}

let Data = [];

let tempObj = {};

for (let j = 0; j < datacell.length; j++) {
  for (let k = 0; k < header.length; k++) {
    if (j % header.length === k) {
      tempObj[header[k]] = datacell[j];
      if (k === header.length - 1) {
        Data.push(tempObj);
        console.log(tempObj);
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(Data);

Whille consoling tempObjs output are as expecting, but when tempObj is pushed to the array the previous elements are overriding by new element.
I was expecting output like
[
  {
    header0: datacel0,
    header1: datacel1,
    header2: datacel2,
    header3: datacel3,
  },
  {
    header0: datacel4,
    header1: datacel5,
    header2: datacel6,
    header3: datacel7,
  }
];

I am getting output like below all the objects are same or overridding
[
  {
    header0: datacel60,
    header1: datacel61,
    header2: datacel62,
    header3: datacel63,
  },
];


tempObj contains a reference to an object, so in every loop you are overriding its previous values, since you are using the same keys. If you want your example to work, you have to use a different object for each loop.
One way to do that would be by cloning tempObj with the Object.assign method:


let header = [];

for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
  header.push(`header${index}`);
}

let datacell = [];

for (let index = 0; index < 64; index++) {
  datacell.push(`datacell${index}`);
}

let Data = [];

let tempObj = {};

for (let j = 0; j < datacell.length; j++) {
  for (let k = 0; k < header.length; k++) {
    if (j % header.length === k) {
      tempObj = Object.assign({}, tempObj);  // <-- added this line.
      tempObj[header[k]] = datacell[j];
      if (k === header.length - 1) {
        Data.push(tempObj);
        console.log(tempObj);
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(Data);



Note: Object.assign only creates a shallow copy. So in your example it works, but if the object were to contain references to other objects, for example, those would not be cloned.
EDIT - As suggested by guriev in the comments, an alternative and more elegant solution, once the issue is understood, is indeed forgoing the tempObj = Object.assign({}, tempObj); line altogether and using destructuring syntax to type, instead of Data.push(tempObj); :
Data.push({ ...tempObj });


Or use Data.push({ ...tempObj });

@guriev indeed, that is simpler. I used Object.assign because it illustrates more clearly the issue and its solution.

Fair enough. Just added as a second option.
